# Using Reacthookforms and Yup to disable fields dynamically

Tags: reactjs, validation, yup, disable

I have been a junior for around 3 weeks and have come to my first problem I cant solve on my own and my senior is away for 2 weeks.

I cant seem to get react hook forms to disable and enable field b once field a is valid.

I tried using isValid() but that returns a promise so cant recheck once field becomes invalid.

I have tried seeing if there are errors and disabling and enabling based on if there are errors which works to a degree but doesn't disable the field if it is empty which in my case would be invalid.

`<input disabled={errors.name ? true : false} />`

https://codesandbox.io/embed/beautiful-mclean-ewmdu?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Any advice would be gratefully recieved

Comment: do you want to disable the coolname field on initial load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I would use **watch()** function from react hook form here. I'm watching input value of full name storing it in a variable and using that as a way to check if I should disable input or not. Here's a not complete code example below:

```
 const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    watch, // Don't forget to pull watch from useForm
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm({
   mode: "onChange",
    resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema)
  });
  // fullName variable value will change anytime there's update to input field
  const fullName = watch('fullname');

  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data);
  ...etc
  return (
    ...etc
     <input
      disabled={!fullName || fullName.length === 0 || erros.fullName}
      className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
      name="coolname"
      {...register("coolname")}
    />
  ...etc
```

Comment: Fantastic that worked perfectly. Have a great evening.